# stored field not retrieved solrcloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am getting an issue with solrcloud the stored field is not reflecting in search where as we are able to get result

see an example below:

```
http://solr:port/solr/cloud1_shard1_replica1/select?q=UCID%3Addfdf4&fl=UCID&wt=json&indent=true
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1157,
    "params":{
      "q":"UCID:ddfdf4",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"UCID",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":13.710121,"docs":[
      {
        "UCID":"ddfdf4"}]
  },
```

But when we add TI in fl there is no documents found

```
http://solr:port/solr/cloud1_shard1_replica1/select?q=UCID%3Addfdf4&fl=UCID,TI&wt=json&indent=true
    {
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":1727,
        "params":{
          "q":"UCID:ddfdf4",
          "indent":"true",
          "fl":"UCID,TI",
          "wt":"json"}},
      "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":13.710121,"docs":[]
      },
      "highlighting":{},
      "spellcheck":{
        "suggestions":[]}}
```

Can any one explain this behaviour of solrcloud

Comment: Does the field TI exist? Is it returned if you query for all fields? `fl=*`

Comment: plz, show your schema.xml

Comment: Yes TI exist, when we are running without solr cloud i.e distrib=false it is showing, but when we are switching to cloud mode it is not showing.